# Importing changes made in a CSV back into Magento

Tags: ce-1.7.0.2, import, importexport

My client used the export tool, made a bunch of changes, and then tried to import it...lo & behold errors everywhere. I didn't get a chance to lead him away from the import/export tools before he went down the road. He did all of this before telling me, so I need to figure out a way to take the data that he changed in the CSV file & import it successfully back into Magento.

Products have been added via the backend since the initial export of the file that all the changes are made in. Would that throw off anything if we did figure out a way to import this back in?

Or is there a way to take just the rows & columns from the CSV that he changed & import just that back in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can 'fix' the import and then reimport I suspect things will come good.  If not restoring a backup database dump is a good option if practical (and available).

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I didn't think of doing this till now, but it worked: I deleted all the rows out that he didn't change, re-saved it, and Magento accepted it. Weird fluke. Thanks for your help though!